# Handle javascript keyboard input in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have this Javascript, which is working fine in IE11 and Chrome, but I need to get it working in IE8!

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey
function checkKey(e) {
   e = e || windows.event;

   if (e.keyCode == "39") {
       window.alert("RIGHT");
   }

   else if (e.keyCode == "37") {
       window.alert("LEFT");
   }
}
```

Why does it not work in IE8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
e = e || windows.event;
```

should be:

```
e = e || window.event;
```